# Convert from user input character to special ascii

Tags: c#, ascii

Example: There is a text box where user input ASCII special character within the text

> "(less than bracket)STX(greater than bracket)Do You Know Da Wae (less than bracket)EOT(greater than bracket)"

the compiler should know how to convert to the following string..

`String str = "\x02Do You Know Da Wae \x03";`

Should use regex to do perform the job or is there any other way to do so?

Comment: `str.Replace("<STX>", "MySpecialString");` ?

Comment: Shouldn't `<STX>` (_Start of text_) be `\x02`, and `<EOT>` (_End of text_) be `\x04`? Seems you are off by one. So something like `string str = sourceString.Replace("<STX>", "\x02").Replace("<EOT>", "\x04");`?

Comment: is ```str.Replace``` only method to go? what i hope is that when user entered ```<>``` string and compiler should try to convert the following command to its ASCII representation ```\x--``` and will have a default ```\x00``` if conversions not successful.

Comment: Should i have a dictionary class to cater for all the value.. Example: ```STX``` key and its value is ```\x02``` this would mean that i have to manually input each of the key and value pair myself  ```Dictionary<string, char>```